# vscode Linker error and undefined symbols (macbook)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am new to C++ and currently having trouble doing OOP with header and source files.
When I build my .h and .cpp files they will not compile in main and I encounter this issue.

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"testt(int, int)", referenced from:
_main in main-e7f174.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Here is a simple code, to my understanding I have defined the functions but why am I still getting an undefined symbols ?

`Log.h`

```
#pragma once

int testt(int a, int b);
```

`Log.cpp`

```
#include "Log.h"

int testt(int a, int b){
    return a+b;
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Log.h"

int main(){
    testt(2,2);
}
```

I've already tinkered with the JSON files, and still No luck.

```
"tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
```

and I have also done

`g++ main.cpp Log.cpp -0 main`

and still no luck.

Thank you everyone for any help provided !

Comment: Your command seems wrong, what is the `-0` option? That's the digit zero, not the small o.

Comment: And please [edit] your question to show the full and complete build log. Copy-paste it as text.

Comment: My fault, I meant to type in the small o not the Zero!

Comment: I often see `"${workspaceFolder}/**.cpp",`, note the second `*`, but that may be a Windows thing.

Comment: Related: [Error when compiling/executing c++ code in Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77533042/error-when-compiling-executing-c-code-in-mac)

Comment: Have you remembered to *save* all your source files? In the terminal, if you run the command `cat Log.cpp` will it display the expected contents?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem of M1 chip's architecture, maybe you should try clang compiler instead of gcc.

Comment: By default on macOS, `g++` is merely an alias for `clang++`. And besides the typo in the manual command, it should have worked. The CPU architecture is irrelevant.